# Perform a function on a subset of rows depending on month?

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

```
Company Month   Price   Quantity
A   1/1/2014    46  4788
B   1/1/2014    43  6242
C   1/1/2014    50  5432
D   1/1/2014    26  4153
A   2/1/2014    21  5301
B   2/1/2014    46  2706
C   2/1/2014    33  9803
D   2/1/2014    42  9208
A   3/1/2014    45  6309
B   3/1/2014    30  9457
C   3/1/2014    20  6050
D   3/1/2014    16  3151
```

I am attempting to perform a simple function `sum(price * quantity)` that is summed for each month in the dataset and send the results to a new dataframe.

The results would look like this:

```
Month   Result
1/1/2014    868232
2/1/2014    946032
3/1/2014    739031
```

I've tried the `aggregate()` function but I'm not having any luck. Is this as simple as the `subset()` function? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'Month', get the product of 'Price', 'Quantity' and `sum` it

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  summarise(Result = sum(Price*Quantity))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Month    Result
#  <chr>     <int>
#1 1/1/2014 868232
#2 2/1/2014 946032
#3 3/1/2014 739031
```

---

Or using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(cbind(Result = Price*Quantity) ~ Month, df1, FUN = sum)
#      Month Result
#1 1/1/2014 868232
#2 2/1/2014 946032
#3 3/1/2014 739031
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That aggregate suggestion is pretty slick.

Comment: Quick question: Right now when I run your aggregate function on a dataset with three year's of data I get a Month results column in a non-chronological order. (That is, 1/1/2014, 1/1/2015, 1/1/2016 instead of 1/1/2014, 2/1/2014, 3/1/2014.) What is your suggestion for sorting that column? Is it possible to do within your aggregate function? Thanks again.

Comment: @R.Baratheon  It is because the column is `character` or `factor` class.  You may need to convert into `Date` class i.e. `aggregate(cbind(Result = Price*Quantity) ~ Month, transform(df1, Month = as.Date(Month, "%m/%d/%Y")), FUN = sum)`

Comment: @R.Baratheon  Also, if there are many days in each month, we need to convert to `Month-Year` i.e. `aggregate(cbind(Result = Price*Quantity) ~ Month, transform(df1, Month = zoo::as.yearmon(Month, "%m/%d/%Y")), FUN = sum)`

Answer (score 0):

The `dplyr` and `lubridate` package lets you group by month and then summarise:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
sum_monthly <- df %>% 
  mutate(Month = mdy(Month)) %>% # Converting month to date format
  group_by(month(Month)) %>% 
  summarise(Result = sum(Quantity * Price))
```